# Definition of Transformation group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request

In an interview today, I was asked the definition of transformation group which I was unable to answer. I tried googling the same but I could not find a precise definition. Can someone please give precise definition or reference for the same?

P.S: I am aware with groups of mobius transformations or orthogonal transformations etc.

Comment: Feels like a non-standard term (or atleast a vague context-dependent term). We have groups, and some examples of groups consist of mappings of a set into itself (e.g the set of bijections of a set $X$ into itself, with composition as the group operation). Or perhaps what they intend is a *group action*, which amounts to a group homomorphism $G\to\text{Sym}(X)$, which then induces a mapping $G\times X\to X$, $(g,x)\mapsto g\cdot x$, where the group element $g\in G$ “acts” on $x\in X$ to produce $g\cdot x\in X$. The mapping $x\mapsto g\cdot x$ is a bijection.

Answer (score 2):

"Transformation group" is a rather standard term. There are several books with this title, see for example [this one](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110858372/html). For beginners, see [this book](https://bookstore.ams.org/stml-25). It is a good reference for your question.

A usual definition is, that a transformation group is a compact Lie group $G$ acting on a topological, usually locally compact, space $X$.

Comment: Hm! I was not aware that "transformation group" (currently) has a precise meaning. I would have thought it just meant "group acting on a set", with further requirements based on context...

Comment: @paulgarrett Yes, I admit, that it sometimes is just a different wording for "groups of transformations", which is more general. But this is a language issue.

Comment: Yes, it is of course a language issue, but/and I was not aware that some specialists assign it a specific meaning... :)

Comment: @paulgarrett, I agree. The definition here is standard for geometric analysts and differential topologists working with Lie groups. But I think something your definition is also reasonable.

Comment: @Deane I saw this term the first time in [Differential Geometry](https://empg.maths.ed.ac.uk/Activities/SUGRA/Kobayashi.pdf).

Comment: Aha! I had seen that Kobayashi book long ago, but at the time read "transformation group" as having a usefully-ambiguous meaning. :)

Comment: @DietrichBurde, that's also the case with me. But I also don't see any reason why it couldn't be used more generally.

Comment: @Deane I suppose we need more details about the context of this "interview", or examination, where this was asked. It might be clear then.